# What is the component I am going to find the voltage for?

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, homework

I recently found the following circuit from an old exam:
[image]

We are supposed to find the voltage V. But... I don't really understand what component that has the voltage V over it... will the V we are seeking be the voltage over the resistors that are vertically positioned, or the ones in series(the ones that are horizontally positioned)?

Answer (score 3):

Call the voltage between the 6 Ohm and 2 Ohm resistor Vx, call the voltage at the negative terminal of the 30V source Vy. I believe the question is asking you to determin Vx - Vy. Of course this is a matter of interpretation, but it seems a reasonable interpretation to me.

Comment: The point being, there is no single component that has V across it.